# List item text is wrapping under the marker before it takes up remaining space

Tags: html, css

I am trying to wrap text in a list item, but for some reason, the text gets pushed to the line under the bullet. Ideally, I want the text to fill the first line with the bullet before it wraps to the next line. I don't want to use list-style-position: outside as I don't want to deal with the bullet being outside of the container.

```css
.list-item {
  display: list-item;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
  testlonglistitemtext
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break#break-all) instead of [`overflow-wrap: break-word`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap#break-word):

```css
.list-item {
  display: list-item;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100px;
  list-style-position: inside;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
  testlonglistitemtext
</div>
```

---

The MDN notes to the two properties summarize the difference.

The note to `break-word`:

> In contrast to ... `overflow-wrap: break-word` ..., `word-break: break-all` will create a break at the exact place where text would otherwise overflow its container (even if putting an entire word on its own line would negate the need for a break).

And the corresponding note to `overflow-wrap`:

> In contrast to `word-break`, `overflow-wrap` will only create a break if an entire word cannot be placed on its own line without overflowing.

In short, the reason for this behavior is that `overflow-wrap: break-word` **tries to fit as much of the word as possible** into the line box before breaking, while `word-break: break-all` **breaks as soon as it needs to** to keep the word within the content box.